# Is there a benefit to storing plain-text (in addition to the HTML data) to improve searchability?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, architectural-patterns

To keep this simple, I intent to store some html based content that is created by the end user.  So a table like the following

```
create table Content
(
   ContentId,
   Title,
   ContentHtml
)
```

Now, the HTML comes from let's say a CKEditor.  Is it good practice to also store the plain text version of the content so that full text search or whatever search mech can more easily find the content?  As shown below.

```
table Content
(
   ContentId,
   Title,
   ContentHtml,
   ContentPlainText
)
```

Comment: Have a look at this. http://www.developmentnow.com/blog/2006/08/12/sql-server-2005-full-text-search-on-html-documents/

Comment: html itself is plain text.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments: absolutely!  There are formatting strings and HTML tags that don't pertain to any conceivable search (unless you're looking for formatting in particular, e.g., someone uses `AliceBlue`).

Also, your indeces are likely to be more efficient, speeding up your searches, if you're not throwing in "junk" like HTML tag names.